# Install rPython under windows

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried to install rPython under windows with `install.packages("rPython")`. However I am getting an error that the package does not exist.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rPython’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)
```

In the installation doc of the package I can only find this:

```
WINDOWS SYSTEMS
===============
On a Windows system, the package can only be installed from source at this time. Details to come.
```

Is there a work-around to work with Python in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try 'rPython-win' if you use windows.
rPython works in Linux.

https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win

Comment: Note the link that hyunwoo gives shows the installation instructions (You don't just go install.packages("rPython-win") like normal, but install with Rtools and devtools)